# how to create iPhone Login/logout App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to create an application with Loginview first view so the procedure is as follows:
Login interface appear if the user is Logout so if it is, another interface that appear with a button to logout or Exit

my question:
how to ensure that when a user is login when the applications Restart directly the second view so appear ?

thx

Comment: Will the user's login details be stored on a server or locally on the iPhone?

Comment: the user's login on the server

Comment: I assume you have a webservice for verifying the user credentials? Do you use HTTPS?

Comment: use iOS 4, so that app goes to background when user clicks home button. And next time user launches the app if topview is not loginview, pop to second view...;).

Comment: yes i use a webservice :) @ mahesh ok i will try now thx :)

Answer (score 2):

You can verify the user’s credentials on application start in the AppDelegate. If the user has valid credentials you can display the logged-in view.

Comment: ok but how i verify if the user's credentials can u give me a code source thx

Comment: @MouMou - It's generally considered rude to ask for source code here, because people aren't going to do your work for you.

Comment: @ brad larson sorry but i don't say to work for me but just i ask for help